# Lax SecurityHeaderLayout doesn't seem to be allowing timestamp to come last

Tags: wcf, soapui

I am using the following binding for my service:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </textMessageEncoding>
    <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
    <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

This defaults `securityHeaderLayout` on the `security` node to `Strict`, which requires the `Timestamp` node in the message to come first.  I am working with another part of the corporation that does not use WCF, so the individual with whom I am working is trying to use SoapUI to test the service.  SoapUI adds the `Timestamp` node at the end of the message.  This can be moved manually, but, apparently, it gets moved back once you sign the node - so you can either have the node come first, or you can have it signed, but not both.

I've tried setting the `security` node to use `Lax` or `LaxTimestampLast`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
<security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax|LaxTimestampLast" />
```

When I call with my own (WCF) client using `LaxTimestampLast`, it fails (`MessageSecurityException: Signing without primary signature requires timestamp.`).  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue recently and I solved it by setting the messageSecurityVersion in my customBinding to a WSSecurity10 version, it had previously had a WSSecurity11 version.  Here is my custom binding that works with both my WCF Client and SoapUI:

```
 <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding">
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                requireDerivedKeys="false"  securityHeaderLayout="Lax"  />            

      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Comment: Is this for the client or the service?  I tried putting this on the service and it did not resolve the LaxTimestampLast issue.